# Any clue for crash report 'String - Couldn't download or retreive file.' got from Sentry - Flutter App?

Tags: performance, flutter, crash

One of my Flutter app on store an that app is integrated with Sentry client for crash reporting.

I got a few crashes and I have fixed most of them based on logs it provides and all I can say Sentry is one of the good solutions for the crash reporting in Flutter.

Unfortunately, I have one crash(Many users are facing it currently) there but I can't able to figure out what it is all about and what should I do to close that issue.

Here is just an overview of an issue and same in the details nothing much on EXCEPTION like stack-trace or so.
[image]

Here is the [public share-able link](https://sentry.io/share/issue/d0acc2ea2b3848a2b88a5f0f56fb0a9c/) for the same.

Anyone has faced similar kind of issue or any clues which can help me to get direction here?

Answer (score 0):

Doing some searching for this, I have found that this is caused by CachedNetworkImageProvider.

In my case, the issue seems to be related to flutter_map and it is raised here: https://github.com/johnpryan/flutter_map/issues/245 - there is also a video link on how to fix this apparently (not sure).

I've also seen this raised in production a few times with very little other information.  (The incorrect spelling of retrieve, means it's a bit easier to search for where this issue happens).